# Can't access dictionary data in boto3

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using boto3, and I ran this loop:

```
for i in x["Instances"]
   print(i)
```

Then I get:

```
{
    'AmiLaunchIndex': 0,
    'Hypervisor': 'xen',
    'VpcId': 'vpc-a790ac1',
    'Architecture': 'x86_64',
    'InstanceId': 'i-0bab3fb8314',
    'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-10-c2.internal',
    'BlockDeviceMappings': [{
        'Ebs': {
            'DeleteOnTermination': True,
            'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 4, 20, 44, 27, tzinfo = tzutc()),
            'VolumeId': 'vol-07fd506f45',
            'Status': 'attached'
        },
        'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda'
    }, {
        'Ebs': {
            'DeleteOnTermination': False,
            'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 6, 1, 12, 45, tzinfo = tzutc()),
            'VolumeId': 'vol-01ef36c45',
            'Status': 'attached'
        },
        'DeviceName': '/dev/sdf'
    }],
    'RootDeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
    'InstanceType': 't2.micro',
    'EnaSupport': True,
    'ClientToken': 'ODrMT1465413',
    'EbsOptimized': False,
    'SubnetId': 'subnet-fb1a4',
    'Monitoring': {
        'State': 'disabled'
    },
    'PublicDnsName': '',
    'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2017-04-06 01:15:22 GMT)',
    'PrivateIpAddress': '10.10.4.116',
    'RootDeviceType': 'ebs',
    'Tags': [{
        'Value': 'wp2',
        'Key': 'Name'
    }, {
        'Value': 'true',
        'Key': 'backup'
    }],
    'ImageId': 'ami-0976f01f',
    'StateReason': {
        'Code': 'Client.UserInitiadShutdown',
        'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown'
    },
    'KeyName': 'pair2',
    'ProductCodes': [],
    'State': {
        'Name': 'stopped',
        'Code': 80
    },
    'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 6, 1, 13, 1, tzinfo = tzutc()),
    'Placement': {
        'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1b',
        'GroupName': '',
        'Tenancy': 'default'
    },
    'SourceDestCheck': True,
    'NetworkInterfaces': [{
        'Description': 'Primary network interface',
        'PrivateIpAddress': '10.10.4.116',
        'PrivateIpAddresses': [{
            'Primary': True,
            'PrivateIpAddress': '10.10.4.116'
        }],
        'Status': 'in-use',
        'SubnetId': 'subnet-ffbcba4',
        'VpcId': 'vpc-a790a7c1',
        'Attachment': {
            'DeleteOnTermination': True,
            'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 4, 20, 44, 26, tzinfo = tzutc()),
            'DeviceIndex': 0,
            'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-c8398',
            'Status': 'attached'
        },
        'Ipv6Addresses': [],
        'OwnerId': '895548',
        'MacAddress': '0e:31:4c4:b6',
        'Groups': [{
            'GroupId': 'sg-26c59',
            'GroupName': 'web-dmz'
        }],
        'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-5383',
        'SourceDestCheck': True
    }],
    'SecurityGroups': [{
        'GroupId': 'sg-2cab59',
        'GroupName': 'web-dmz'
    }],
    'VirtualizationType': 'hvm'
}
```

I'm trying to access the 'VolumeId' using something like:

```
for x in ["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]:
   print(x)
```

I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

It looks like 'BlockDeviceMappings' starts as a list with a dictionary in it, but I can't get to 'VolumeId'.

I've also tried:

```
for x in ["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]:
   for k,v in ["Ebs"]:
      print(v)
```

And I get:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

And I tried:

```
 for x in ["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]:
    for v in ["Ebs"]:
       print(v)
```

Which prints 'Ebs' several times.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get VolumeId please use

```
print x["Instances"][0]["BlockDeviceMappings"][0]["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]
```

you just missed x or _. 
You are getting an error because ["BlockDeviceMappings"][0] evalutates to "B".
So you trying getting "orb" from "B"

To get all volumes:

```
for i in x["Instances"]:
    for b in i["BlockDeviceMappings"]
        print b["Ebs"]["VolumeId"]
```

If you have to extract data from complex sturctures like that often, try some quirky search library like github.com/akesterson/dpath-python , it can extract data just using keywords

Comment: Thanks, but that gets me the first volume. If there are more it skips that. That's the main problem, which I probably didn't explain well.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Comment: any time, Regretfully computer does guess which array or dictionary you need even if you mentioned it in the previous line... Let's hope one day AI or language designers will provides something easier like